# Jenkins GO run fails with git 128

Tags: go, jenkins

Folks, am trying to run some go tests.  Seems to be a failure with git configuration on the box?

Am running `git version 1.8.3.1` before someone asks... go version `1.13.1`

Builds pass for me locally on my mac and linux... but seem to fail in Jenkins

```
go test -v ./... -tags=unit
go: bitbucket.org/xxxxxxx/yyyyyyy@v1.0.82 requires
    cloud.google.com/go/storage@v1.6.0 requires
    cloud.google.com/go@v0.53.0 requires
    cloud.google.com/go/bigquery@v1.3.0 requires
    golang.org/x/exp@v0.0.0-20191030013958-a1ab85dbe136: invalid version: git fetch --unshallow -f https://go.googlesource.com/exp in /var/lib/jenkins/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/879ce674f4d9f0a3a3f207a6503e782bb2113f1a3d0c1f8049cc523b96d9aa9e: exit status 128:
    fatal: git fetch-pack: expected shallow list
make[1]: *** [unit-test] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/xxxxxx/yyyyy'
make: *** [test] Error 2
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
[Slack Notifications] found #1 as previous completed, non-aborted build
[Slack Notifications] will send OnEveryFailureNotification because build matches and user preferences allow it
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution was simple, bump up the version of `git` in GCP